# Laravel returning a blank page only on certain routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I'm having an issue where a route is returning a blank page. I am using `Homestead` as my dev environment and I'm unsure how to debug.

The `/storage/logs/laravel ...` isn't returning any exceptions when I visit the white page.

**web.php (where it's failing):**

```
Route::get('/clinic/register', 'ClinicController@register');
```

**Controller.php:**

```
public function register()
{
    return view('clinic.register', ['specialisms' => Specialism::pluck('specialism', 'id')]);
}
```

Yet when I visit `/clinic/register` I am shown a blank white page. How can I see why it's failing? Surely a white page will return an exception somewhere?

Comment: Is youre view name and path is `resources\views\clinic\register.blade.php`? If yes, please show this view.

Comment: Yes, that's where the view is. I currently just have a `<p>hello</p>`.

Comment: Your code looks ok. Try to clear view cache with `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: Just tried that, still returns a blank page.

Comment: All other views work fine?

Comment: Some of them do, some of them return a blank page. What's frustrating is that no log is showing these blank pages.

Comment: please check the file name is correct or not register.blade.php in view

Comment: @Ben, so what's common in these routes? Can you give examples of both?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As you have not provided your entire route setup. This answer is my best guess. See if it helps.

Your issue hint at improper route setup. If you have created a **clinic** resource then **clinic/register** route should precede it.

```
// clinic/register route should come first
Route::get('clinic/register','ClinicController@register');

// followed by rest of the routes which resource will create
Route::resource('clinic','ClinicController');
```

The reason behind getting a blank pages is because Route::resource will create some route with wildcards. 
For e.g. clinic/{clinic} which will map to show method on controller. So when you make a get request to **clinic/register** it will be mapped to this **show** method instead of your **register** method.

One possibility for not getting any errors is your **show** method does not have any code yet. Hence, a blank response.

To summarize: **Order in which you register your routes matters**

Comment: you were quite right. I had a Route::get('/') at the top, many thanks!

Comment: Awesome, you really saved my day on a similar issue!