# Laravel 5.3 500 error on specific routes

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have a Laravel 5.3 app that i work on windows xampp locally. I just move it on a live centos 7 server.
What i've done so far:

- I created a virtual host on the live server
- I changed .env file with new database credentials
- I changed storage folder permissions to 777
- I cleared the cache (cache:clear)

The issue is that some of the routes work just fine and other don't.
e.g.
This route `Route::resource('admin/permissions', 'PermissionsController');` works fine
But this route `Route::resource('admin/users', 'UsersController');`
doesn't

I followed this answer [Laravel returning a blank page only on certain routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40451599/laravel-returning-a-blank-page-only-on-certain-routes) but had no luck

EDIT: *It is not duplicate-The error came from another reason

Comment: what is the error, check your log file

Comment: @StateLess no error either on laravel log or apache log.

Comment: Try clearing all your cached data. `php artisan route:clear` `php artisan view:clear` and `php artisan clear-compiled`

Comment: Does the php user on centos have rights to create the log file?

Comment: @StateLess now every route give 500 error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting a 500 Internal Server Error on Laravel 5+ Ubuntu 14.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31543175/getting-a-500-internal-server-error-on-laravel-5-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: Have you checked your php_error.log?

Comment: 500 error usually comes with a log entry explaining what it is. That may be a laravel log or a webserver log

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that might have the same issue while moving from Windows xampp to Centos 7 server:
The problem was that on Centos in a few models the table name had the first letter capitalized. This is no issue for windows but it is for Centos.