# Laravel showing blank page for only one route site.com/admin, all other non existing route goes to 404 page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

Problem:
When i access non existing route it shows 404 page `except site.com/admin`, it shows blank page.

my `web.php` file,

```
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware'=>'auth:admin'], function () {

        Route::POST('readnotification','NotificationController@readnotification')->name('readnotification');

        Route::GET('/home','AdminController@index')->name('admin.dashboard');
....
```

Full web.php file is here https://pastebin.com/embed_js/pZNmPih8

Tried:

1) I have seen `php artisan route:list`, `/admin` route is not exist.

2) I removed all routes, and accessed a non existing route then it shows 404 page, `except site.com/admin`, as usual it shows blank page.

3) Even i emptied the web.php file, but still /admin is blank and other urls going to 404

I really don't know whats happening.

Comment: Do you have `Route::GET('/` inside group ?

Comment: @C2486, no i have something like this `Route::GET('/home','AdminController@index')->name('admin.dashboard');`

Comment: I think it works if you go to `/admin/home` ? Right

Comment: yes, `/admin/home` works

Comment: Please post your Nginx / Apache  site config

Comment: Im out of office, its ubuntu apache 2.4 i think

Comment: @paras, can u tell me how server config affect this i try to solve it

Comment: You may have setup a separate route in your server config. So that may be the issue. Just lookout for the routes configured in your Apache config

Comment: try php artisan route:clear and take a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/40452482/12927017

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have not created any directory inside **public/** as same as your route name. If you have **/admin** directory inside **public/** then your **/admin** route will not work and show blank page without any error. Anything inside **public/** directory will not show as 404 page instead of that it will show a blank page

Answer (score 0):

As you commented that you have below route to get work if you go to `/admin`

```
     Route::get('/home','AdminController@index')->name('admin.dashboard');
```

Then it should be just `/` inside admin group , or add it as another route to get both route work

```
    Route::get('/','AdminController@index')->name('admin.dashboard');
```

Comment: tried that, and ran `php artisan route:clear`, still showing blank page